# How to add Wordpress header and footer to vBulletin 5 site

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, header, vbulletin

I'm trying to find a way to add my site header and footer from my wordpress blog to wrap my vBulletin 5 forum. I found all sorts of tutorials and guides online on how to do this using plugins to pull in the php files in vBulletin 4, but it seems plugins are no longer available in vBulletin 5.

Has anyone done this yet?

Comment: Maybe check the WordPress StackExchange: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hope this link will help you out of the issue :-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580818/how-to-add-wordpress-header-and-footer-in-vbulletin-4-2/16608050#16608050